# What's the difference between @ and $ and % in MSBuild?

Tags: .net, msbuild

What are the differences when referring to variables in MSBuild.  For example in the following there is a `@` and `$` and as well as a `%` used.

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(Files)" DestinationFolder="$(TempBuildDir)\%(RecursiveDir)">
   <Output TaskParameter="CopiedFiles" ItemName="DeployFiles" />
</Copy>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

$ denotes access to a property (some kind of variable that contains a simple value)

@ is for item, which typically is a group of files with attached metadatas under a name

% denote an access to a metadata of an item. There are [wellknown metadatas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx) (like RecursiveDir, see the definition in msdn) automatically attached to an item, or you can attach your own metadata when you define your items

lets say you define @(files) like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Files include='c:\source\**\*.*'>  <!-- all files in all subfolder in c:\source -->
     <Color>Blue</Color> <!-- attach metadata color = 'Blue' to these files -->
   </Files>
   <Files include='c:\source2\**\*.*'>  <!-- all files in all subfolder in c:\source2 -->
     <Color>Red</Color> <!-- attach metadata color = 'Red' to these files -->
   </Files>
</ItemGroup>
```

if c:\source contains files 1.txt, b/2.dll , c/3.xml, and c:\source2 contains a/4.exe,   @(Files) is formed like this

- file c:\source\1.txt, with metadata
  color = 'Blue' and RecursiveDir = ''
- file c:\source\b\2.dll, with metadata
  color = 'Blue' and RecursiveDir = 'b'
- file c:\source\c\3.xml, with metadata
  color = 'Blue' and RecursiveDir = 'c'
- file c:\source2\a\4.exe, with
  metadata color = 'Red' and
  RecursiveDir = 'a'

If you define TempBuildDir like this

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <TempBuildDir>c:\temp<TempBuildDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You have some kind of variable that contains a simple value : c:\temp

Your examples reads like this : copy every files defined in item File in a directory that is formed by concatening value of variable TempBuildDir with the Recursive directory where you found the file.

You end up with :

- c:\temp\1.txt
- c:\temp\b\2.dll
- c:\temps\c\3.xml
- c:\temp\a\4.exe

Comment: Great detailed answer thanks. I would vote this up more times than the one allowed :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is the complete list of the special characters:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-special-characters?view=vs-2019